# Controller not passing database variable to php file

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a controller with a function:

```
<?php
require_once 'models/UserModel.php';
require_once 'models/AdvertisementModel.php';

class HomeController {
    public function index() {
        require 'views/index.php';
    }
    
    public function userList() {
        $users = UserModel::getAllUsers();
        require 'views/user_list.php';
    }
    
    public function advertisementList() {
        $advertisements = AdvertisementModel::getAllAdvertisements();
        require 'views/advertisement_list.php';
    }
}
?>
```

And a php file that should list my users like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>User List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>User List</h1>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($users as $user) : ?>
            <li><?= $user['name'] ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, this is the UserModel.php:

```
    <?php
class UserModel {
    public static function getAllUsers() {
        global $db;
        $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
        return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}
?>
```

On the php page, I get the error:

> Warning: Undefined variable $users in user_list.php

As far as I know, the connection to the database is working, so I am not sure what to do, I am also kind of new to working with databases. I am using MySQL on Windows.

Comment: Is that the entire contents of `user_list.php`? I would guess some kind of [scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) issue. But we don't seem to have a [mre] of the issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your question when you have code to share. As you can see, it's really not very readable like that.

Comment: After `$users = UserModel::getAllUsers();` you could also put `var_dump($users);` to check that the model code returned a value, and see what it contains.

Comment: Just to be 100% clear, the code you are describing as `a php file that should list my users like:`...this is `user_list.php`, am I correct? And the line causing the error is `foreach ($users as $user)`...is that also correct? You did not mention the line number from the error message, or point us to it (since we can't see your line numbers anyway).

Comment: Yes, correct. Also, vardump returns Warning: require_once(models/UserModel.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in F:\Programs\xampp\htdocs\Advertisements\controllers\HomeController.php on line 2

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'models/UserModel.php' (include_path='F:\Programs\xampp\php\PEAR') in F:\Programs\xampp\htdocs\Advertisements\controllers\HomeController.php:2 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in F:\Programs\xampp\htdocs\Advertisements\controllers\HomeController.php on line 2

Comment: models/UserModel.php exists, I'm not sure why it fails to find it

Comment: var_dump doesn't cause that, but perhaps you only just noticing this error for some reason, as it would be the `require_once 'models/UserModel.php';` line which threw the error (as per the message). Anyway I would guess that the path you've used simply isn't correct _relative to the current executing script_. Read https://phpdelusions.net/articles/paths to find a good way to deal with paths in your PHP applications.

Comment: e.g. if the current script is in `/controllers`, and `/models` is not a subfolder of `/controllers` then that would explain why the path you've used doesn't work. If `/controllers` and `/models` are at the same level in the folder hierarchy, then `../models` would work as a relative path to find that folder, from a script in the `/controllers` folder. But really you should try to use absolute paths wherever possible, making use of environment variables to ensure the code is still portable - see the guide.

Comment: Please don't use irrelevant tags - or explain how the given error message is related to HTML or MySQL